# CSS - How make the page scroll over the edge of the window

Tags: html, css

How would one go about crating the same effect only using CSS as on this website:
http://a-gerace.com/index.php/photography/box-elder-co-ut/

Where if you scroll to the right, the page continues over the borders of the page using CSS?

Comment: Can you please add some better description (screenshots, sketches or similar) to better describe what you want to achieve? Links tend to rot overtime, so later viewers of the questions might not get what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see with inspect element / view source:

```
#img-container {
    width: 20000px;
}
```

and of course `display:block`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You must set width to images container like this site. For example 20000px;

Answer (score 0):

simply add a position: absolute or fixed (as you want) div and set the content inside (depending on content) a proper display style (display:inline-block for example) and add overflow-x on it (the div that acts as container). It should work "as is" without js (regarding the example you linked)